# NSAnimationContext misbehaving

Tags: cocoa, nsanimationcontext

I have a button that triggers the main window to animate it's height thus displaying some options in a pull-down-menu. The button (and it's sibling) are placed in the two bottom corners of the window, so i want them to animate down with the window - being "locked" in a fixed distance from the bottom window edge.

**Problem:** The buttons animate properly maybe 1 out of 10 times - the rest of the time they get offset seemingly randomly on the y-axis. On top of that the two buttons get different offsets - they don't behave identical, although the animation code is the same.

Deployed and run on OSX 10.9 Mavericks the animation works properly - no misbehaving there.

Any ideas on how to get the following, simple code to work on OSX < 10.9?

```
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0.2f];
    [[[self window] animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect([self window].frame.origin.x, [self window].frame.origin.y-EXTRA_HEIGHT, ORIGINAL_WIDTH, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT+EXTRA_HEIGHT) display:YES];
    [[_buttonOne animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint([_buttonOne frame].origin.x, CONSTANT_NUMBER)];
    [[_buttonTwo animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint([_buttonTwo frame].origin.x, CONSTANT_NUMBER)];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Comment: You're sure there's no autolayout used in your XIBs? Kind of sounds suspicious..

Comment: It sure is suspicious; "Use Autolayout" is not activated in my XIBs. Maybe my approach is wrong - "animating" the button from/ to the same coordinates. Meta-animation.